# Temporary table with two tables data with no column in common should return data in one column

Tags: sql

I have following temporary table

```
Create table #Test
(
colA int,
colB int,
colC int,
colD int,
colE int
)
```

I insert the data in it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO #Test(colA, colB, colC)
Select A, B C
FROM Table a innerjoin Table b
WHERE (some logic)

INSERT INTO #Test (colD, colE)
Select D, E
FROM Table C innerjoin Table D
WHERE (some logic)

Select * from #Test
drop table #Test
```

I will get output as :

```
colA colB colC colD colE
val1 val2 val3 null null
null null null val4 val5
```

But I need output as follows :

```
colA colB colC colD colE
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
```

Please help me to achieve it.

Comment: But what if the two joins return different number of rows?

Comment: As @jarlh says, you seem to assume there's only one row from each query. But assuming that's right, just make the second `insert` an `update`.

Comment: @Namrata is there any relation between (Table a and Table C) or (Table a and Table D) or (Table b and Table C) or (Table b and Table D)?

Comment: No there is no relation between tables column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below query

```
Select max(col1), max(col2), max(col3).... from #Test
group by col1,col2,col3....
```

Comment: Works well with this very limited amount of data. But what will happen when more rows are added?

Comment: @jarlh  what problem do you see with large amount of data?